# How do I solve Complex Number questions like: Given that $|z|=\sqrt{3}$, solve $2z^*+3/(iz)=\sqrt{15}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I go about to solve the following question.

given that $|z|$=$\sqrt 3$, solve 2z*+ ${3\over iz}$ =$\sqrt {15}$

Comment: Have you tried solving for $z$ in form $a+bi$?

Comment: I tried solving with $a+bi$ but I think I still an't solve it that way.

Comment: Also is the star complex conjugate and regular script $z$ real part?

Comment: You should show what you've tried and not just ask someone to do it for you.

Comment: the z* is the complex conjugate. |z| is $sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ when $z=a+bi$

Comment: But the $z$ script/font also is different?

Comment: I did try. I spent like a solid hour already on what is supposed to be a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single way to solve questions about complex numbers. In this case we can use the fact that $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\bar z}{|z|^2}$, so your equation becomes:
$$
2\bar z-i\frac{3\bar z}{3}= \sqrt{15}
$$
$$
\bar z(2-i)=\sqrt{15}
$$
Can you do from this?

Comment: I don't know if that's valid since the question is from a high school (IB) textbook and that isn't covered in the textbook.

Comment: And how is defined the inverse of $z$?

Comment: And how is anyone to know what solutions are useful to you and what aren't? If you had shown your work perhaps it would have been beneficial to YOU. Or is it req

Answer (score 0):

Using $z^\ast=\frac{3}{z}$, $\frac{6-3i}{z}=\sqrt{15}$ (since $\frac{1}{i}=-i$) so $z=\frac{6-3i}{\sqrt{15}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $\space\exists\space\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\frac{1}{\text{z}\cdot i}=-\frac{\Im\left(\text{z}\right)+\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\cdot i}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\tag1$$

And, so we also get:

$$2\cdot\overline{\text{z}}+\frac{3}{\text{z}\cdot i}=2\cdot\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)\cdot i\right)-3\cdot\frac{\Im\left(\text{z}\right)+\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\cdot i}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\tag2$$

For the real and imaginary part:

- Real part:
  $$\Re\left(2\cdot\overline{\text{z}}+\frac{3}{\text{z}\cdot i}\right)=2\cdot\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{3\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\tag3$$
- Imaginary part:
  $$\Im\left(2\cdot\overline{\text{z}}+\frac{3}{\text{z}\cdot i}\right)=-2\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{3\cdot\Re\left(\text{z}\right)}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\tag4$$

Now, when:

$$\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}=\sqrt{3}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)=3\tag5$$

So the real and imaginary part become:

- Real part:
  $$\Re\left(2\cdot\overline{\text{z}}+\frac{3}{\text{z}\cdot i}\right)=2\cdot\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{3\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)}{3}=2\cdot\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)\tag6$$
- Imaginary part:
  $$\Im\left(2\cdot\overline{\text{z}}+\frac{3}{\text{z}\cdot i}\right)=-2\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{3\cdot\Re\left(\text{z}\right)}{3}=-2\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)-\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\tag7$$

Now, we can set up a system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\Re\left(2\cdot\overline{\text{z}}+\frac{3}{\text{z}\cdot i}\right)=2\cdot\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)=\sqrt{15}\\
\\
\Im\left(2\cdot\overline{\text{z}}+\frac{3}{\text{z}\cdot i}\right)=-2\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)-\Re\left(\text{z}\right)=0\\
\end{cases}\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space\begin{cases}
\Re\left(\text{z}\right)=2\cdot\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\\
\\
\Im\left(\text{z}\right)=-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\\
\end{cases}\tag8
$$